# Java / Scala - ReactiveStreams / Enumeratee How to continually read an Input Stream until read() returns -1

Tags: java, scala, playframework, reactive-streams

currently I have a Publisher[InputStream] how could I know read it to have something like the Java8 Streams API provide:

```
def binStream(is: InputStream) = Stream.continually(is.read).takeWhile(_ != -1).map(_.toByte)
```

Currently I use Scala and the playframework and want to chunk the Output via the experimental akka-streams / reactivestreams libraries, however I have no clue, due to the fact that there is little to no documentation about both things. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

akka-streams has the [InputStreamSource](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/?_ga=1.183478818.562096145.1438263138#akka.stream.io.InputStreamSource$) which takes an InputStream in its constructor.

There is a fair bit of documentation on Akka Streams [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/scala.html?_ga=1.213224976.562096145.1438263138)

If you are interested in the play iteratee library (you put the `play-framework` tag in your question) you can use [Enumerator.fromStream](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator$@fromStream(input:java.io.InputStream,chunkSize:Int)(implicitec:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator[Array[Byte]]) method to make an Enumerator.

There is also a fair bit of documentation about Play's Iteratees [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Iteratees)